# How do define the account addresses when running truffle test?

Tags: unit-testing, truffle

By default truffle uses **testrpc** / **truffle develop** which has a list of predefined addresses:

```
Truffle Develop started at http://localhost:9545/

Accounts:
(0) 0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57
(1) 0xf17f52151ebef6c7334fad080c5704d77216b732
(2) 0xc5fdf4076b8f3a5357c5e395ab970b5b54098fef
(3) 0x821aea9a577a9b44299b9c15c88cf3087f3b5544
(4) 0x0d1d4e623d10f9fba5db95830f7d3839406c6af2
(5) 0x2932b7a2355d6fecc4b5c0b6bd44cc31df247a2e
(6) 0x2191ef87e392377ec08e7c08eb105ef5448eced5
(7) 0x0f4f2ac550a1b4e2280d04c21cea7ebd822934b5
(8) 0x6330a553fc93768f612722bb8c2ec78ac90b3bbc
(9) 0x5aeda56215b167893e80b4fe645ba6d5bab767de
```

How can I overwrite or add addresses ?

Answer (score 1):

You can Run TestRPC with accounts of your choice.
For Doing that, Use

`testrpc --account "<private-key>, balance"`

For Example you want one account with private key = `64fa61f689c54ffdc73b048d7ebf7fb55953cb4c8deb2553e3615f7c2f459a6b`, append a `0x` in the begining of this private key such that it becomes  `0x64fa61f689c54ffdc73b048d7ebf7fb55953cb4c8deb2553e3615f7c2f459a6b`, Now run,

`testrpc --account "0x64fa61f689c54ffdc73b048d7ebf7fb55953cb4c8deb2553e3615f7c2f459a6b, 100"`

This will run testrpc with one account with private key = `64fa61f689c54ffdc73b048d7ebf7fb55953cb4c8deb2553e3615f7c2f459a6b`

If You want to create more than one accounts,

`testrpc --account "<private-key>, balance" --account "<private-key>, balance"` so on..